# setAdapter in RecyclerView cannot be applied

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

Имеется код класса

```
package asus.example.com.exercise3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView previewImages;
    private final List<Actor> actors = DataUtil.generateActors();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        previewImages = findViewById(R.id.previewImages);
        previewImages.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(actors, this));
    }
}
```

И код адаптера для RecyclerView

```
package asus.example.com.exercise3;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<Actor> actors;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Context context;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Actor> actors, Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.actors = actors;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return actors.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Actor getItem(int position) {
        return actors.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View galleryItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preview_image_layout, parent, false);
        ImageView avatar = galleryItem.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        Actor actor = actors.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(actor.getSmallImage()).into(avatar);
        return galleryItem;
    }
}
```

Однако программа не компилируется и ругается на строку         `previewImages.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(actors, this));`

Подчеркивает ее и пишет: setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter) in RecyclerView cannot be applied to asus.example.com.exercise3.RecyclerViewAdapter. В чем проблема?

Comment: потому что `BaseAdapter` не является `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter`, вы не можете от него наследовать

Comment: BaseAdapter можно в ListView использовать но не в RecyclerView